# How to send http body without the 'POST / HTTP/1.1' header using pycurl?

Tags: python, curl, struct, pack, pycurl

I send some data to mysockserver listening on a socket and expecting data as follows

```
packet='A'+struct.pack("!I", 98)+"Hello World blah blah"
```

It works all fine.
Now I need to send above data to above socket sitting behind http mytcpipserver.com. mytcpipserver.com is redirecting messages to mysockserver. I tried following

```
csocket = pycurl.Curl()
csocket.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'https://mytcpipserver.com:443')
csocket.setopt(pycurl.PROXY, 'myproxy.com:8080')
csocket.setopt(pycurl.PROXYPORT, 8080)
csocket.setopt(pycurl.VERBOSE, 1)
csocket.setopt(pycurl.HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1)
headers = ['POST', 'Expect: ', 'User-Agent: ', 'Host:', 'Accept:', 'Content-Length:', 'Content-Type:']
csocket.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, headers)
header = "A" + struct.pack("!I", len(message))
packet = header + message
csocket.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, packet)
csocket.perform()
```

I can see that msg is reaching to mysockserver as follows but I want to see server receiving only raw data i.e. 'A'+struct.pack("!I", 98)+"Hello World blah blah"

```
"POST / HTTP/1.1

A<rest of message>"
```

mysockserver was not expecting arrived msg to start with POST but with A+PackedInteger+MoreData.
Basically, how do i send just the raw data without any header?

**SO the question now is, how to send body without the header "POST / HTTP/1.1"?**

Answer (score 0):

Don't use pycurl, directly use the `socket` module. Pycurl is for sending http requests, and your server obviously is *not* a http server, as the integer you're getting is part of the raw POST request:

```
>>> binascii.unhexlify(hex(1330861088)[2:])
'OST '
```

Simple example how it should work:

```
import socket

packet='A'+struct.pack("!I", 98)+"Hello World blah blah"
conn = socket.create_connection(('target_host', target_port))
conn.send(packet)
# ...
conn.close()
```

Also, you're trying to dump binary data using `json.dumps`, but json per definition uses unicode, so that won't work, and is probably not what you actually want.

Comment: Unfurtunately, I can reach target host (i.e. MyServerListeningOnSocket) only as follows httpProxy:8080->https:/blahblah.com:443->MyServerListeningOnSocket

Comment: socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_HTTP, 'proxyBlah.com', 8080);  socket.socket = socks.socksocket;  c = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM);  c.connect(('blahblah', 443));  header = "Q" + struct.pack("!I", len(message));  packet = header + message  c.sendall(packet);  giving me error socks.py", line 349, in __negotiatehttp  raise HTTPError((statuscode,statusline[2]))  socks.HTTPError: (400, 'Bad Request'). I have added semicolon just to make code clear since i do not know how to add new line after each line in this comment section